# Is there a eventlistener in eclipse core for "OnFileOpen"?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I am trying to write a plugin which parses the source code of any opened (java) file.

All I have found so far is `IResourceChangeListener`, but what I need is a Listener for some kind of "onRecourceOpenedEvent".

Does something like that exist?

Comment: Opened by what? Java builders and the like open lots of files all the time. Or do you mean opened in an editor?

Comment: yes opened in an editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest you can get to this is to use an `IPartListener` to list to part events:

```java
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getPartService().addPartListener(listener);
```

In the listener the `partOpened` tells you about a new part opening:

```java
public void partOpened(IWorkbenchPart part) {
  // Is this an editor

  if (part instanceof IEditorPart) {
     IEditorPart editor = (IEditorPart)part;

     // Get file being edited

     IFile file = (IFile)editor.getAdapter(IFile.class);

     // TODO file is the current file - may be null
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to implement this, but it seems the start method in the Activator class is called too early, i get an java.lang.IllegalStateException: Workbench has not been created yet. Is there a way to "wait" for the initiation of the IDE to be finished before starting the plugin?